# Pentaho CDE how to use parameter in SQLQuery

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde

I'm looking a sample dashboard "Map Component Full Test".
I want to replace the datasource of pie chart for "sql over sqljdbc".

How can I use parameter in SQLQuery?

I'm waiting for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use parameter in SQL Query,
write Query like this.

Query:
select * from table 
where id = ${parameter_name}

And another property should be set like this.
parameter:
Arg ← parameter_name , 
Value ← not set (this value is affected  by graph component's setting)

※here, "parameter" does not mean the components, like "Simple
 parameter". 
 They are not same.